# Запятая перед или

Tags: запятые, или

Добрый день! Подскажите, необходимо ли после "кислота" поставить запятую?

Витамин С, или аскорбилпальмитат, или аскорбиновая кислота – защищает от ...

Answer (score 1):

(1) "Витамин С, или аскорбиновая кислота, защищает от ..."

Здесь ИЛИ - пояснительный союз в значении ТО ЕСТЬ, если предмет имеет два разных названия.

Три разных названия одного предмета  в предложении встречаются не часто, можно предположить, что это будет так: 
(2) "Витамин С, или аскорбилпальмитат, или аскорбиновая кислота, защищает от ..."

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Но, кажется, аскорбилпальмитат и аскорбиновая кислота - это не одно и то же. Аскорбилпальмитат  - сложный эфир пальмитиновой кислоты и аскорбиновой кислоты.

Answer (score 0):

Указанная запятая нужна, т.к. здесь пояснение.

София, это одно и тоже.Читайте здесь: http://www.quickiwiki.com/ru/%C0%F1%EA%EE%F0%E1%E8%ED%EE%E2%E0%FF_%EA%E8%F1%EB%EE%F2%E0

Comment: Не могу прочитать, страница не открывается. Но если это действительно три названия одного вещества, то достаточно запятых, тире не нужно.